# Collision Detection Kit package error

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, compiler-errors

I am making a top-down walk around game in flash, and am using the Collision Detection Kit to handle collisions. When I try to run my game, it gives me this error message in the compiler error box:

> `5001: The name of package 'com.coreyoneil.collision' does not reflect the location of this file. Please change the package definition's name inside this file, or move the file. /Users/student/Google Drive/School/Game for Mr Crawford/CollisionGroup.as`

What is wrong, and what should I do to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means you have a `package` declaration which does not match the location of the .as file. For example, if you have an .as file with the following:

```
package my.sub.pack.name
{
    //
}
```

It needs to be found in the folder `SOURCE_PATH/my/sub/pack/name/`. Note a default `SOURCE_PATH` is the same directory as your FLA.